# What is "design flexibility" in UI frameworks?

Tags: swing, mfc

In the Pro Android 2 book, the authors refer to 4 generations of UI frameworks (in order):

1. C-based MS Windows API
2. C++-based MFC
3. Java-based Swing
4. Android UI, JavaFX, Microsoft Silverlight, Mozilla XUL

In that section, the authors say that Swing introduced "design flexibility far beyond that offered by MFC."

What does "design flexibility" mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the things that Swing introduced was the idea of a pluggable look and feel. This meant that a component such as a label could be placed on the screen, in the place you wanted it to exist. Then you could customise how that component looked by using any number of UI platforms.

Furthermore, Swing gave you access to the paint methods, so you could simply draw the component yourself if you could not find the UI that you wanted to use.

I have found swing to be extremely flexible in building user interfaces from the layout managers, ui component customisation through look and feel, and the ability to override the paint methods, or implement your own UI delegate class. All of these things I think make up design flexibility and pushed the boundaries of what was available before.

Comment: thanks and +1. I understand what you wrote about the pluggable look and feel. That was definitely a new introduction. As for access to the paint methods, however, are you sure this was new? AFAICR, "owner draw" in the Windows API allowed you the same exact thing. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I am not saying all these things were new, it is just Swing gave you lots of options brought together that gave you lots of flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to create a UI based on artistic creativity instead of say a grid pattern